# Where can I find a global heat map of travel spots?

Tags: online-resources, sightseeing, maps

For example, if I were to plan a trip between Munich and Berlin by car, it'd be great to have a quick glance at a map that would give me a quick idea on where the interesting spots are. That way there's no need to stumble over dozens of pages on Wikitravel to see if there's something cool in the area that's easily reachable on a drive like this.

I've found a good example of an [attractions heat map of London](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3373097/London-s-photographed-attractions-revealed.html):

[image: London heat map]

Is there something similar on a global scale?

Comment: Have you tried foursquare or panoramio*?
(* Assuming that a high photo density is a very interesting touristic place)

Comment: good old Michelin maps, highlight pretty driving roads

Comment: @JonathanReez not sure if this would qualify but try using [Strava](https://www.strava.com/heatmap) although it is related to 'activities' it does show good areas to hike, cycle etc.

Comment: That's great to know what places to avoid visiting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that TripAdvisor has a convenient map mode which could be used to find the most popular destinations in a given area. For example, [here's their map](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attractions-g154943-Activities-Vancouver_British_Columbia.html#MAPVIEW) for Vancouver:

[image: vancouver tripadvisor]

Google Maps has the potential to be just as useful if they let you search for the most reviewed locations in a given area, but unfortunately this feature is not available yet, although you can find a list-based form on [Top-rated.online](https://www.top-rated.online/).

Answer (score 16):

Here's what I'm aware of:

- [Sightsmap](http://www.sightsmap.com) (which I think comes closest to what you are looking for)
- [Heatmaps of Flickr photos and Twitter tweets](https://www.flickr.com/photos/walkingsf/sets/72157627140310742/with/5926359544/)
- [Flickr heat maps](https://www.flickr.com/photos/walkingsf/sets/72157623971287575/)
- [Flickr heat maps distinguishing between locals and tourists](https://www.flickr.com/photos/walkingsf/sets/72157624209158632/)
- The above two sets of images available as [a browsable global heat map](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/twitter-gnip/locals/#3/20.72/-147.66)
- [Flyover Country](http://fc.umn.edu) shows you what's beneath you on your flight
- [A KML file](http://www.bluemoon.ee/~ahti/touristiness-map/touristiness-map.kml) detailing the 'touristiness' of places and [another KML file](http://www.bluemoon.ee/~ahti/touristiness-map/interesting-remote-places-map.kml) with interesting remote places

Comment: Sightsmap is gone, sadly. I haven't found any other one that is not centered in cities

Answer (score 8):

The most detailed heat map at global scale, that shows the most relevant, popular places is this:
http://www.instasights.com/map/

Try to search or just zoom-in into any city on the planet to see how accurate it is.

Comment: It's a nice map, but it feels like the source has a strong bias for cities over natural attractions.

Comment: @glaux Don't most tourists?